# How to stop image with transparent background from being black?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, user-interface

I'm trying to add an image to my Image UI and the image has a transparent background to it but in unity it just shows up black?
if anyone can help it would be very good!

[image: Settings]

[image: Image with black background]

[image: Normal Image]

Answer (score 1):

Click on the texture type button and select the sprite
[image: ref]

Comment: You might also have to enable `Alpha is Transparency` but afaik this should be the default ;)